# Is there a way to get only the changed columns from an object using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

In a persistent object, If i change only one field, Is it possible to find out the changed field only through Hibernate? 
I know I can get the entire old row and new row and compare.

Comment: at what point do you want the changed row? before saving, after saving, after a while?

Comment: @Bozho Before saving, so that I can log which column got updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to hook into Hibernate's event system (see [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events)). For example, if you registered to receive [`FlushEntityEvent`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/event/FlushEntityEvent.html), then you'd be informed as to which columns were changing via the `getDirtyProperties` method of the event.

Comment: Links sadly  broken

Answer (score 7):

On the basis of one of your comment, my understanding is that you are looking for an auditing solution so I suggest to check [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) which is exactly about this.

> The Envers project aims to enable easy auditing/versioning of persistent classes. All that you have to do is annotate your persistent class or some of its properties, that you want to audit, with @Audited. For each audited entity, a table will be created, which will hold the history of changes made to the entity. You can then retrieve and query historical data without much effort.

Comment: Yes I was looking for an auditing solution. But envers tells weather an audited field has changed or not and not which field changed. Also it requires separate tables to store the audit data.